# How to check for a collection in MongoDB using Node.js?

Tags: mongodb

Saw another thread to turn it into an array like this without using Mongoose? I see this asked previously but many answers are outdated.

```js
let colArr = await db.listCollections({}, { nameOnly: true }).toArray();
```

Is there a cleaner way to do it? Looking to create a new collection if it doesn't exist, otherwise just declare that collection

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb is permissive, creating a new collection with any command that names it.  The specific task of creating a collection is typically only needed to be done by a dba when the collection is to have specific properties such as being capped.

[createCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/index.html)

Comment: In my case, I'm creating a forum (learning project) like reddit where each thread is a collection so users should be able to create a new one. I thought let collection = await db.createCollection('collectionName'); wouldn't be best practice for creating if doesn't exist but naming if exists.... right? Or is that common practice..?

Answer (score 0):

```
/* returns an array of collections in the database */
db.getCollectionNames() // MongoDB 3.0 & above
```

Note:- [db.getCollectionNames()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/):-  Returns an array containing the names of all collections and views in the current database, or if running with access control, the names of the collections according to user’s privilege. For details, see Required Access.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
  var db1 = mongoClient.db("mydb");
  const collectionName = 'nameOfCollection'; // name of the collction you want to search in database.
  db1.listCollections({name: collectionName }).toArray(function(error, collection) {
      if(error){
        throw err;
      }
      if(collection.length > 0){
        console.log(collection.length) // number of collections in database

      } else {
        console.log("No collections found!")
      }
  });
  mongoClient.close();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you happen to know why this doesn't work? Board is a variable for any collection name.
const col = await (db.hasCollection(board)) ? db.collection(board) : db.createCollection(board);

Comment: @wongz, Sorry bro. I did not get you. Are you talking about this answer?